# Visualizing a graph between 3 lists in Python

Tags: python, graph

I have 3 lists:

A1, A2, ... Am

B1, B2, ... Bn

C1, C2, ... Ck

Each Ai, Bi, Ci represents a node.

The relationship are:

one A node links (directed links) to several B-nodes.

one B node links (directed links) to several C-nodes.

one A node might link to other A-nodes in term of parendOf and childOf.

I want to make a graph as below:

[image]

What is the best way to create a graph like this in Python? Can I make an interactive graph?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by interactive ? I believe the best way to create this would be to use a graphic lib such as `matplotlib`. First, create your graph, then, plot your data points and lines using X,Y coordinates.

Comment: Can you post your lists?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact the problem is solved easily by using networkx library.

Thanks for your answers.